# running Xubuntu on usb

Tags: usb-flash-drive, xubuntu, liveusb

I want to be able to run Xubuntu on usb. I have made the usb bootable using pendrivelinux, and set persistence to the maximum so I can save changes I make. The question I have is: Is it safe to go to "Install Xubuntu" ? Or will it ask me to format Windows drive? I am asking this because I figured there was not a lot I could with "Try Ubuntu".

Comment: You probably need to use an extra usb drive or so, so that one will be the installation medium (made with pendrivelinux or whatever), and the other one will be the target of installation. Also, it will never been real safe unless you disconnect the Windows drive. All kinds of PEBKAC or installer silliness could happen.

Answer (score -2):

yeah it' safe, you can install it alongside with W7.

Comment: Can you cite a source for your suggestion?

Comment: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-xubuntu.html

Comment: Perhaps adding the info from the link would help reduce the down votes.